# Higher Prediction Error in after Preprocessing using PCA with Neural Networks in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, pca

I am using `PCA` before feeding the training set into a neural network. It reduces 13 features down to 8 and trains over 2200 training sets. The MAPE I get with this is close to 2.5 - 2.6 %.
If I train the raw data with simple `feedforwardnet`, I get a lower error of 2.1%.

I am suffering from a similar situation in a different problem, where I have close to 50000 training sets where PCA gives 2.5% error and simple ANN gives me ~2% MAPE.
What is the reason behind this? Is this a normal occurrence? Can you give me any way by which I can reduce the error? I am trying to forecast the electric load demand on the basis of weather and previous load data.

EDIT: (Added Scree Plot )
[image]

Comment: PCA reduces the dimensionality of the data without knowing whether particular dimensions are informative or not. So yes, it is entirely possible that your nn performance gets worse after PCA.

Comment: Can you show your [scree plot](http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/17/topic-library/modeling-statistics/multivariate/principal-components-and-factor-analysis/what-is-a-scree-plot/)?

Comment: @user2441151 From the scree plot, you probably only need 3-4 principal axes since it drops off rapidly from there. Can you post your data or something I can actually run (a toy example)? There are many reasons behind this that could be related to the training procedure, but I'm guessing it's an implementation error. If that's the level of detail that you want, I can give you an answer right now. Also can you post the architecture that you tested with? What transfer function are you using?

Comment: @user2441151 Basically I need a [minimum reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you need specific pointers

Comment: @krisdestruction - I have uploaded the data here
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8B_cRUnpH78flhwbmhONzZIVi1vU0RSRTllRXA1RVJiN2dwVFFzSXl6Q0c4RERVWGVvSk0&authuser=0


I simply used this code:

`[pn,meanp,stdp] = prestd(X');
[ptrans,transMat] = prepca(pn,0.01);
X = ptrans';`

Then went on to train ANN using X as usual.

Comment: @user2441151 Can you show the code of how you trained it as well?

Comment: @user2441151 I assume you're also doing the MAPE calculation after the training. Can you also post the code on how you do that calculation too?

Comment: @krisdestruction

Added the code file to the drive as well.
`netFeb = newfit(trainX', trainY', networkConfigFeb);
netFeb.performFcn = 'mae';
netFeb = trainlm(netFeb, trainX', trainY');

forecastLoadFeb = sim(netFeb, testX')';
errFeb = testY - forecastLoadFeb;
errpct = abs(errFeb)./testY*100;
MAPEFeb = mean(errpct(~isinf(errpct)));`

Comment: @user2441151 Please add the code to the question next time. I did it for you this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem as you back a few Months ago but with SVMs instead of NNs. So the reason why you're getting such poor results is because you haven't normalized your data before feeding it into the PCA function. You can do this using Matlab's [mapminmax function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mapminmax.html). Since mapminmax noramlizes the rows, you need to do a transpose of the input and output as follows.

```
[normX,PS] = mapminmax( X' );
normX = normX';
max( normX )   % Returns 1
min( normX )   % Returns -1
```

To plot the scree plot, you can use this code.

```
[C,~,~,~,explained] = pca( normX );
figure; plot( explained );
```

This is the Scree plot. You can probably keep the first 5 components of your data.

[image]

After you perform the minmax mapping, you can feed it into your NN as follows. This assumes you want to keep PC 1-5.

```
trainX = normX * C(:,1:5);
```

Now if you ever need to transform your noramlized data back to

```
returnedX = mapminmax( 'reverse', normX', PS );
returned = returnedX';
```

Collectively your code should be as follows

```
% Normalize Data
[normX,PS] = mapminmax( X' );
normX = normX';
max( normX )   % Returns 1
min( normX )   % Returns -1

% Perform PCA
[C,~,~,~,explained] = pca( normX );
figure; plot( explained );

% Transform Data
trainX = normX * C(:,1:5);
```

**EDIT:** Performance
The code I used to test performance is below.

```
clear all
load input
load output

% Normalize Data
[normX,PS] = mapminmax( X' );
normX = normX';
max( normX )   % Returns 1
min( normX )   % Returns -1

% Perform PCA
[C,~,~,~,explained] = pca( normX );
figure; plot( explained );

% Transform Data
trainX1 = normX(1:1826,:) * C(:,1:5);
trainX2 = X(1:1826,:);
trainY = dailyPeakLoad(1:1826);
testX1 = normX(1827:end,:) * C(:,1:5);
testX2 = X(1827:end,:);
testY = dailyPeakLoad(1827:end);

netFeb = newfit(trainX1', trainY', 35);
netFeb.performFcn = 'mae';
netFeb = trainlm(netFeb, trainX1', trainY');
forecastLoadFeb = sim(netFeb, testX1')';
errFeb = testY - forecastLoadFeb;
errpct = abs(errFeb)./testY*100;
MAPEFeb = mean(errpct(~isinf(errpct)));

netFeb2 = newfit(trainX2', trainY', 35);
netFeb2.performFcn = 'mae';
netFeb2 = trainlm(netFeb2, trainX2', trainY');
forecastLoadFeb2 = sim(netFeb2, testX2')';
errFeb2 = testY - forecastLoadFeb2;
errpct2 = abs(errFeb2)./testY*100;
MAPEFeb2 = mean(errpct(~isinf(errpct2)));
```

The trained NN are here. This is the one with PCA.
[image: NN1]
This is the one without PCA.
[image: NN2]

Note that performance is different because of initial values and number of iterations.

Comment: networkConfigFeb = 35. I'll get back to you in some time. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: @user2441151 np, can you accept the answer (when you test it) if it's correct? :)

Comment: The error is still higher . I used `prepca` instead of `pca()` as it showed `not found`. 
`[C] = prepca( normX );`
Not sure what the issue is now.

Comment: @user2441151 How many PC did you keep? What Matlab version are you using (since you might be using an older one)? You should use `pca` instead of `prepca` if you can as `prepca` is depreciated.

Comment: @user2441151 Also as always, edit your question with the code that you tried :)

Comment: I used the same code as you mentioned. Only replaced the one line by the one I wrote in the previous comment. I am using 2011a.

Comment: @user2441151 Can you check if you have the function `princomp`? It's the predecessor to `pca`. You should update your version if you have a chance.

Comment: @user2441151 Also can you upload testX/testY for me or perhaps put it in your input/output.mat. That's part of reproducing the issue.

Comment: I have given all the data I have in the input/output.mat. Both have 2191 rows of data. I used the first 1826 for training and the last 365 for testing.

Comment: @user2441151 Ah okay sorry I didn't see that in your code. So after running [this script](http://pastebin.com/MyPirSYk), I see that the error is the same. That is `MAPEFeb == MAPEFeb2 == 2.8112` but the PCA one runs for less iterations. Can you confirm?

Comment: True. PCA runs for less iterations. I do not get same error though.
EDIT: I run a different code for the forecast. So, yeah, with your code, it may be same. Do you think PCA can reduce the error in this case?

Comment: @user2441151 Just to correct you, PCA does run for more iterations in this case but that's probably because you got a simple example. When you run PCA, you make the tradeoff of throw away some data to attain less dimensions. It is useful if your data is correlated. If it isn't, you don't need to use PCA.

Comment: @user2441151 In my research, I use PCA to reduce 1000 features to something like 2 features. It's useful because I do time series data which is usually highly correlated.

Comment: @user2441151 I still think you should use PCA, but you can play around with the number of dims you truncate. PCA should generally allow you to generalize the solution space better though and reduce iterations due to the reduced feature dimension.

Comment: @user2441151 Sorry to spam, but I should also note that since you're building an NN for each month, you can probably use a loop.